# EKEvent Startdate cannot set programmatically in iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, ekevent

I am trying to assign date for EKEvent startdate property as below, 
Code is:

`My CustomEKEvent.h file`

```
@interface CustomEKEvent : EKEvent<NSCoding> 
{


}
```

`My CustomEKEvent.m file`

```
-(id)initWithEvent:(EKEvent*)event

{

    self.startDate = event.startDate; // Whats wrong in this code? but its working fine in iOS 4.3

}
```

Output is :

```
event.startDate :2012-07-25 06:30:00 +0000

self.startDate :(null)
```

Anyone know the solution. let me know.

Thanks in advance.